# Cannot install APK in some Android phones: "Unknown mime type to import"

Tags: android, apk

as the title states, on some phones, the APK installs fine.  On some others, the error is "Unknown mime type to import" upon trying to install.  What is the cause of this error?

Thank you.

Comment: I assume you're trying to install it without ADB and without going through Google Play. And I also assume you've checked the box "install from other locations" (or something like that). Some gmail clients and some internet browsers don't recognize the apk mime type. The quickest fix is to download an application from Google Play which solves this very issue. There are a number of them, just do a search.

Comment: Yes, I'm actually just sending the APK file to a co-worker and he's trying to install it via email attachment for review.

Comment: You may want to ask your co-worker to save the apk on the phone first, then open it. Possibly the email client your co-worker used may not be able to open .apk file

Comment: Thank you, yes it was the email client that was the problem.  Switching to gmail client worked!